# Need help. Having hard time installing cocoapods

Tags: installation, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods onto my computer. I did the following:

sudo gem update--system
Password:
 and I got the following text:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command update--system

Kind of confused as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to update gems before installing cocoapods, you need to do

```
sudo gem update --system
```

You forgot the space between `update` and `--system`.

To install cocoapods, you need to use the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```